# Jquery select proper id inside foreach loop

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have a foreach loop that renders about 10 different links inside of it and they all share a common **ID** and different **names** , when a user clicks on a link I would like Jquery to perform a specific function which I can already do. The part I am having trouble with is how can I make Jquery notice which link has been clicked; this is my code and it should clear things up

Jquery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mee").click(function (e) {
            if ($(this).text() == "[+]") {

                $("#mee").text("[-]");
            }
            else {
                $("#mee").text("[+]");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

page

```
    foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
        {
             <a id="mee" style="color: #980000" name="@item.ThreadpostID" href="#">[+]</a>
           }
```

I know that this works because the First element of the loop always responds correctly but all other elements do not work. If you look at the foreach loop you will see a variable in the name and that is always an integer so the loop id,name will always be something like

- ID=mee   Name= 5
- ID=mee   Name= 23
- ID=mee   Name= 11

with that said how can I change my Jquery code above to include the proper **Name** identification so that the correct link functions when it is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all the id attributes on your page should have unique values.

A solution (off the bat, untested) could be:

```
    foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
    {
         <a id="@item.ThreadpostID" class="mee" style="color: #980000" name="@item.ThreadpostID" href="#">[+]</a>
    }
```

(notice how the value "mee" has been transferred to the class attributes, which works fine with duplicates)

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mee").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).html() == "[+]") {

            $(this).html("[-]");
        }
        else {
            $(this).html("[+]");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked greatly and I have changed it to class.